# Do I need all my previous passports for UK visit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm currently living in Germany as an expat and I'm planning to visit UK in a couple of months. My question is do I need all my previous passports along with my current one for the application? Will it have any impact because I didn't bring with me my previous passports that are expired to Germany just my current one that only has a German visa and no prior travel history.

I already looked at the document requirements and they don't list it but has it under additional requirements. Can some one help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: How old is your current passport? Unlikely that anyone expects you to keep your old passport for ten years, but if your brand new passport is one month old, there may be suspicion that you want to hide some evidence from the old passport.

Comment: I'm Pakistani and my current passport is around 7-8 months old.